# Does MSAL.js support the check_session_iframe OIDC endpoint?

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, msal.js, duende-identity-server

I'm working on an SPA which depends on an instance of [Identity Server](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer) for authenticating users. I need a solution that manages my tokens locally, but Duende (the owners of Identity Server) lean towards a Backend For Frontend (BFF) pattern over Javascript libraries. This isn't going to work for us. Since the original oidc-client that was written by the authors of Identity Server is no longer maintained I've been looking at Javascript alternatives. The most likely candidate would seem to be Microsoft's [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) which is built for Azure AD, but supposedly supports OIDC standards.

From what I can tell, MSAL.js forces you down an offline_access path using refresh tokens to renew security tokens. Even if I don't expressly require an `offline_access` scope the library appends one anyway! But my use case doesn't require refresh tokens. Instead I want my client to keep the session on the identity provider fresh using OIDC session mamnagement standards (via the check_session_iframe endpoint exposed by the provider's well-known JSON).

I have found that if I ignore the `offline_access` scope requested by the MSAL.js library so my identity provider only issues and ID token and an access token then MSAL continues to work just fine. It even has an `ssoSilent` option for explicitly renewing the tokens via a connect/authorize request in a hidden iframe. But as far as I can tell I can't have the library keeping that session fresh via an iframe like the old oidc-client used to.

So given that session management is part of the OIDC specification, and MSAL is supposed to be an OIDC-compliant library, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time MSAL.js does not have an API that integrates with the `checksession` endpoint. If you would like to see this added, you are welcome to open a PR on [our Github](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues).

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Good to have a clear answer. In my implementation it may not be needed, but I'll look at writing the code if we need it 

Comment: It would be useful to understand why this wasn't included. Is MSAL.js currently intended to be an offline access only library, so using refresh tokens rather than session state? I'm curious because afaik generally refresh tokens in the browser are discouraged.

Comment: A couple reasons: first, ADAL.js and MSAL.js did not use the checksession endpoint, and second, because MSAL.js uses the Auth Code Flow to mitigate issues caused by third-party cookie blocking. So yes, v2 uses a refresh token to acquire/renew access tokens, as opposed to a cookied request in a hidden iframe.

Comment: And the guidance has changed around browser-based applications, which are now encouraged to use the Auth Code Flow w/ PKCE (which MSAL.js implements) instead of the implicit flow: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#section-4

Comment: First comment should say: "ADAL.js and MSAL.js v1 did not use..."

Comment: Sorry @jasonnutter I only just saw these comments. I'm well aware that implicit flow is not advised, but there are also reasons relating to browser security to avoid refresh tokens in the browser if possible. AFAIK there's no explicit requirement to pair code+PKCE flow with offline_access scope. It should be possible to ignore that scope and use OIDC session management without refresh tokens. I realise that has its own concerns (cross-origin iframes) but it's still for now part of OIDC spec.

Comment: We are aware of the potential risks, which is why refresh tokens returned to MSAL.js v2 are short lived (24 hours). And there is a feature request in our backlog to enable applications opt out of receiving a refresh token, but we haven't had a chance to prioritize it.